# What corresponds to JMPREL on x86 in mips

Tags: mips, dynamic-linking, abi, got

I try to use plthook code(https://github.com/kubo/plthook) in mips
but it not supported. so i try to porting now.

In x86 abi, dynamic section has JMPREL. so it is allowed to  relocation.
but in MIPS binary(i compiled same binary through gcc cross compiler) don't have it.
(plthook code use it)

i try to find dynamic linking in MIPS but i can't find well document.

so

1. do you know What corresponds to JMPREL on x86 in mips
2. do you know MIPS's dynamic linking reference  ??